# Error to execute powershell: System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx

Tags: c#, powershell

I try execute powershell script with HelloWorld, but I see error.My script:

```
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Powershell.exe -File HelloWOrld.ps1");
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {

        }
```

In exception I see:

> "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified  at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(String fileName)   at InstallAzurePowershell.Program.WritePowershell() in c:\Users\titans\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\InstallAzurePowershell\InstallAzurePowershell\Program.cs:line 111"

So how it's fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong overload. The [version used](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/53ezey2s) `Process.Start(String)` will take one string as an argument. It considers the whole string as application name. So instead of running `powershell.exe` and passing `-File Hello.ps1` you are trying to run an exe called `"powershell.exe -File hello.ps1"`. This obviously makes little sense to the OS.

Use the [proper overloaded version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h6ak8zt5): `Process.Start(String, String)`.